# Is this Scanner bug in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsscanner

I have a sample code using Scanner class.
I expected that *resultString* has **" testing & testing1&testing2"**
However, *resultString* is ***"testing &testing1&testing2"***

When `scanUpToString()` function called, I guess the scanning string is trimmed.
Is this bug? or not?

```
let testString = " testing &amp; testing1&amp;testing2"
let scanner = Scanner(string: testString)
var resultString: String = ""

while scanner.isAtEnd == false {
    if let beforeString = scanner.scanUpToString("&") {
        resultString += beforeString
    }
    
    guard scanner.isAtEnd == false else {
        break
    }
    
    if let scanResult = scanner.scanString("&amp;") {
        resultString += "&"
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check for `&amp;` before `&` as you might trip over yourself here. I wouldn't be so quick to assume a bug in Swift.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, and certainly opinion-based: The `guard` statement has important use-cases, but I still prefer a simple `if scanner.isAtEnd { break }` over this “double negation.”

Comment: whitespace and newline characters are skipped by default.

Comment: It's not a bug, please read the documentation of [scanUpTo(_:into:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner/1411971-scanupto). The convenience function `scanUpToString(_:)` behaves the same way.

Comment: Oh my... Thank you For all. I didn't know existence of [chcaractersToSkipped](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner/1410204-characterstobeskipped)